# Check value exist in table or not while using oracle regular expression substring

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am inserting a comma separated sting values to table by using [oracle regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm). Before insert I have to check these condetions.
If The Unit Name is Exist then skip to next.
Else insert and continue to next. My sample code is

```
PROCEDURE SP_INS_UNIT(
        P_UNIT_NAME   VARCHAR2,
        P_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2)
    AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TM_UNIT
        ( UNIT_NAME, DESCRIPTION
        )
      SELECT UNIT_NAME,
        P_DESCRIPTION
      FROM
        (SELECT regexp_substr(P_UNIT_NAME,'[^,]+',1,level) AS UNIT_NAME
        FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_UNIT_NAME,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        );
```

Any help for this highly appriciate.

Comment: Why do you work with comma-separated strings when you have a relational database at hand in the first place? This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am a new one to database. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Jzl comma-separated strings aren't really a thing in SQL they way they are in some 3G languages. You can write code to handle them but it's complicated and inefficient.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to use a `Not exists` condition like this?

```
      ..
      ..

      SELECT UNIT_NAME,
        P_DESCRIPTION
      FROM
        (SELECT regexp_substr(P_UNIT_NAME,'[^,]+',1,level) AS UNIT_NAME
        FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_UNIT_NAME,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        ) s 
where not exists
(
 select 1 from TM_UNIT t where s. UNIT_NAME = t.UNIT_NAME
);
```

Comment: Exactly. This is what I am looking for.